# Search Text File and Email Results

Tags: python

Working with a text file to search for a string and then email the nex few lines.

I have the search working and it prints the correct lines 
The email sends successfully, however it only contains the last line of the output

Any thoughts?

File.txt

```
first
second
thrid
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
after first
after second 
after thrid 
after forth 
after fifth
after sixth
```

my code

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_address = "fromaddress@domain.com"
to_address = "toaddress@domain.com"


with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" in line:
            for l in searchlines[i:i+6]: print l,
            output = l

            msg = MIMEText(output)
            msg['Subject'] = "Test email"
            msg['From'] = from_address
            msg['To'] = to_address

            body = output

            # Send the message via local SMTP server.
            s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.domain.com', '8025')

            s.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())

            s.quit()
```

Output via print:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
after first
after second 
after thrid 
after forth 
after fifth
```

The email only contains in the body

```
after fifth
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is wonky.  The loop should collect the lines, then you should send an email when you have collected them all.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
# <-- unindent; we don't need this in the "with"
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    # Aesthetics: use "-" * 78
    if "-" * 78 in line:
        for l in searchlines[i:i+6]:
            print l,
        # collect all the lines in output, not just the last one
        output = ''.join(searchlines[i:i+6])
        # if you expect more than one result, this is wrong
        break

# <-- unindent: we are done when the for loop is done
# Add an explicit encoding -- guessing here which one to use
msg = MIMEText(output, 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = "Test email"
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address

# no point in assigning body and not using it for anything

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.domain.com', '8025')
s.sendmail(from_address, to_address, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

The real bug was that `output = l` would only collect the last value of `l` after the innermost `for l` loop, but restructuring the program to not do things in a loop when they should only happen once (and vice versa!) hopefully makes it clearer as well.

If there can be more than one result, just removing the `break` will not suffice -- this would reinstate your original bug in a different form, where only the last match of six lines will be sent.  If you need to support multiple results, your code needs to combine them into one message somehow.

Comment: ah ok i see, so collecting the output in result. orig.encode('ascii')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: I missed the place where you create the MIMEText body part -- updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

your for loop prints all the lines, but then the loop ends, and l is set to the last item in the loop: after fifth

then you email that last l